# Rails: Any way to generate Active Admin views (add nested forms)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is there anyway to generate [Active Admin's](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) views? I know how to override them but I'd like to keep their basic layout but just add some nested forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Active Admin [Documentation](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html), there is no way to generate all views:

You can create forms with nested models using the has_many method:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Post do

    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :title
        f.input :published_at, :label => "Publish Post At"
      end
      f.inputs "Content" do
        f.input :body
      end
      f.inputs do
        f.has_many :categories, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Themes', :new_record => false do |cf|
          cf.input :title
        end
      end
      f.actions
    end

  end
```

1. The :allow_destroy option will add a checkbox to the end of the nested form allowing removal of the child object upon submission. Be sure to set :allow_destroy => true on the association to use this option.
2. The :heading option will add a custom heading to has_many form. You can hide a heading by setting :heading => false.
3. The :new_record option will show or hide new record link at the bottom of has_many form. It is set as true by default.

Comment: Where at in the documentation does it say "you can not generate a view"?

Comment: if there will be a way to generate views, it will be mentioned in documentation.